# Infinite loop in my vba access program why?

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
schsql = "SELECT obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.cpt_cde_cl, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.no_int_lig_cde_cl, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.no_int_cde_cad_cl, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.no_int_ord_fab, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.dte_liv_conf_cde_cad_cl, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.dte_hre_exp_prev, obi_cl_cde.pt_bloq, obi_cl_cde_lig.pt_force_sld, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.pt_sld_cad, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.qte_liv_cde_cad_cl, obi_cl_cde_lig.pt_att_lig_cde_cl, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.pt_prev_cde_cad_cl, obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.qte_cde_cad_cl, obi_ordfab.cd_etat_ordfab " & vbCrLf
schsql = schsql & "FROM obi_ordfab RIGHT JOIN (obi_cl_cde INNER JOIN (obi_cl_cde_lig_cad INNER JOIN obi_cl_cde_lig ON (obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.no_ste = obi_cl_cde_lig.no_ste) AND (obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.cpt_cde_cl = obi_cl_cde_lig.cpt_cde_cl) AND (obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.no_int_lig_cde_cl = obi_cl_cde_lig.no_int_lig_cde_cl)) ON (obi_cl_cde.no_ste = obi_cl_cde_lig.no_ste) AND (obi_cl_cde.cpt_cde_cl = obi_cl_cde_lig.cpt_cde_cl)) ON (obi_ordfab.no_int_ord_fab = obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.no_int_ord_fab) AND (obi_ordfab.no_ste = obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.no_ste) " & vbCrLf
schsql = schsql & "WHERE (((obi_cl_cde.pt_bloq)=""0"") AND ((obi_cl_cde_lig.pt_force_sld)=""0"") AND ((obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.pt_sld_cad)=""0"") AND ((obi_cl_cde_lig_cad.qte_liv_cde_cad_cl)<[obi_cl_cde_lig_cad]![qte_cde_cad_cl]) AND ((obi_cl_cde_lig.pt_att_lig_cde_cl)=""0""));"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(schsql)
If Not rst.RecordCount = 0 Then

    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF

        'If rst!no_int_ord_fab = 62432 Then Stop
        'rcset.FindFirst ("OF=" & rst!no_int_ord_fab)

        chsql = "Select * FROM admin_inventaire_expedition where no_int_cde_cad_cl = " & rst!no_int_cde_cad_cl & " AND Emplacement = """ & "EXPE" & """ "
        Set rcset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(chsql)

        If Not rcset.EOF Then

            rcset.Edit
                rcset!cpt_cde_cl = rst!cpt_cde_cl
                rcset!no_int_lig_cde_cl = rst!no_int_lig_cde_cl
                rcset("Date expé") = rst!dte_hre_exp_prev
                rcset("Date livraison") = rst!dte_liv_conf_cde_cad_cl
            rcset.Update

        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End If
```

My program make an infinite loop, i just change my rst recordset query in order to be more fast, but why infinite loop please?

Comment: Please add you put your code in a code block and maybe just include that parts that might be helpful in answering the question. See [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure it is an infinite loop, and not that you have a significantly sizes `recordset` which just takes a while for VBA to go through?

Comment: Did you test the query SQL in query designer? The query should not cause infinite loop. The code is repeatedly editing the same record in rcset. Have you step debugged?

Comment: I test the SQL query in designer and it works fine, the schsql query is very fast under 3 seconds, but when it goes to update in the loop, it takes too much time, maybe i update many times the same lines

Comment: I can't try this on my computer but I would start with printing some identifiers of rst before retrieving rcset. Maybe editing the records resets the selection query and rst moves to the first record again.

Comment: Thanks i found a solution, by modify a query, because i set a join between the table i want to update and the others tables where data come from, otherwise if i don't make this join it doesn"t work, thanks for all help :)